# How does one stream and play Youtube/FLV videos in a C++ application?

Tags: c++, streaming, flv

I would like to stream and play Youtube videos, or FLV files in general, in a C++ application.  How can it be done? (I'm using QT as a GUI)

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems to tackle.

First one you need the player technology. For that you can use ffmpeg but bear in mind that it is licensed under GPL (older version in LGPL).

The second thing is that you need access to the FLV video urls. For this you either scrape the website or used the YouTube GData APIs. If you decide to go for the latter you need to know that you'll need a special deal with YouTube/Google to be granted access to the high quality streams. Usually you don't get access to the FLV ones.

Comment: what do you mean by "high quality streams" you mean HD ? 
i need the ordinary ones , do i need still youtube permission ?

Comment: Via GData API YouTube makes available a 3gp and a mpeg4 video streams. The quality of these videos is a bit choppy <100kbps. The videos you see on the website are flv videos with much higher bit rate and for these you need specific YouTube permission.

Answer (score 0):

How about Qt with Phonon plus a backend that can decode flv streams?

Comment: can you please give me more info about that ?